# Using NSPredicate on NSArray containing 2 elements

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

Newbie Questions.

I have 2 Class, both are subclass of NSObject, AddressBook class and AddressCard Class.

**AddressBook has**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *bookName;

@property (nonatomic , strong) NSMutableArray *book;
```

while

**AddressCard has**

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *name, *email;
```

---

I put addressCard instances into AddressBook instances

.name and .email into book.

so my main.m will look like this

```
AddressCard *card1 = [AddressCard new];
AddressCard *card2 = [AddressCard new];


[card1 setName:@"Tony Stevenson" andEmail:@"TnT213@mail.com"];
[card2 setName:@"Ian Hicks" andEmail:@"BBn12@mail.com"];

AddressBook *myBook = [[AddressBook alloc]initWithName:@"Roland's Address book"];

[myBook addCard:card1];
[myBook addCard:card2];
```

Question 1, How do I show my array containing address Cards using only single Line?

I know another way (showList method), **but I am curious why my** `NSLog(@"%@",myAddressBook.book)` didn't work. and only logged this out :

```
my book (
    "<AddressCard: 0x1001083e0>",
    "<AddressCard: 0x10010a7a0>",)
```

---

```
- (void) showList{

   // NSLog(@"%@",book);

    NSLog(@"====== Contents of: %@ =======",bookName);


    for (AddressCard *theCard in book) {
        NSLog(@"%-20s    %-32s", [theCard.name UTF8String], 
                                 [theCard.email UTF8String] );
    }

    NSLog(@"===============================");
}
```

Question 2, `How do I filter name on myAddressBook array using NSPredicate with Like parameter?`

I have tried but XCode still throw an exception

//in this code I wanted to filter .name elements starting with stev

```
NSPredicate *execPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF 
  contains[c] 'Stev'"];

  NSArray *Contain = [myBook.book filteredArrayUsingPredicate:execPredicate];

  NSLog(@"%@",Contain);
```

Could anyone give me some guidance on this problem? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSLog(@"%@",myAddressBook.book)` uses the `description` method to print the array elements, which, by default, prints the class name and address. But you can 
override the `description` method in your `AddressCard` class by adding the
following to "AddressCard.m" (as an example):

```
-(NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name:%@ email:%@", self.name, self.email];
}
```

---

In your `NSPredicate` you have to specify the *key* for filtering, for example:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] 'Stev'"]
```

or better

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name contains[c] %@", @"Stev"]
```

The second form works even if the search term contains special characters like `'`.

Comment: since AddressBook Class didn't know name and email, I simply put it in AddressCard Class. it worked.

Comment: @user3213703: You are right, I have mixed up the two classes, sorry for that. Answer corrected.

Comment: oh yeah, also regarding to modifying description method, does it mean that without modifying description method, it will only NSLogged class that object belongs to and addresses of that object.

in my case, it only  logged elements of myBook array containing object from AddressCard Class and its address? so basically, myBook array didn't own that object? thanks, sorry for asking too much.

Comment: @user3213703: Your problem has nothing to do with ownership (NSMutableArray owns its elements). - NSLog() calls the description method, and if you don't implement that in your class, it is *inherited* from the NSObject class. The description method from NSObject just prints the class name and the object address.